# Get webpage and read throug it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a quick question, say that you would like to connect to a website and search it for what links it contains, how do you do this with javascript? 
I would like to do something like this

```
Var everythingAdiffrentPageContains = //Go to some link ex www.msn.se and store it in this variable

var pageLinks  = [];  var anchors    = everythingAdiffrentPageContains.getElementsByTagName('a');  
var numAnchors = anchors.length;
for(var i = 0; i < numAnchors; i++) {     
     pageLinks.push(anchors[i].href); 
}
```

We can assume here that we have acces rights to the site so this is not of a concern.

In other words I would like to go to some site and store all that sites Hyperlinks in an array, how would you do this in javascript?

Thanks

EDIT since pointed out Im **not** trying to connect to another domain. Im trying to connect to another apache webserver inside my lan that hosts a website that I would like to scan for links.

Unfornuatley I do not have PHP on my webserver :/ But a simple javascript would do it

for example go to X:/folder/example.html

Read it, and store the links

Comment: Inside your LAN or not doesn't matter, if it's on another server, e.g. the address bar in your URL is different, then you can't get there, see the link to the same origin policy in my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - You can't do this. "We can assume here that we have acces rights to the site"...that's a false assumption from a JavaScript point of view, if the page is on **another domain**.  You simply can't access content on another domain (not HTML content anyway) via JavaScript.  It's prevented by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), in place for several security reasons.

Comment: Some desktop applications that execute JavaScript in a browser-like context aren't bound by the same-origin policy, like Windows Desktop Gadgets, for instance.  If that's the case, though, the OP should specify.

Comment: @Andy - very true, in the absence of anything not-browser mentioned I am assuming they're in a browser, but I'm playing the odds there :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a JS framework that helps you to retrieve elements and do stuff with DOM easily.
For example using mootools you could achieve this writing some code like this:

```
var req = new Request.HTML({
   url:'./retrieve.php?url=YOURURL', //create a server script to "retrieve" the html of another domain page    
   onSuccess: function(tree,DOMelements) {
       var links = [];
       DOMelements.getElements('a').each(function(element){
           links.push(element.get('href'));
       });
   }
});
req.send();
```

The retrieve.php page should be written for example in this way:

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: Unfornuatley I do not have PHP on my webserver so I cant use it :/

Comment: You can use the serverside scripting lang you want ;) ..it's just an example to explain how to retrieve an external webpage html using a server side script. If you want to do this JUST in js you can't. :)
What do you have on your webserver?

Comment: What _do_ you have on your server?